# Blade helper, get variable from view without parameter

Tags: php, laravel-4

maybe someone know, how can I get variable with name "foo" from blade template get to static function which is used in this template.

For example  I have:

```
<div class="collumns large-8">
 {{ Helpers::setLetters('variable_name') }}

</div>

<div class="collumns large-8">
 {{ $variable_name }}

</div>
```

Both divs should set same string because in setLetters function will be

```
return ${$name};
```

But, that should be instead $name, because in case about, will be error.

I use laravel 4.1

Comment: temporarily I use View::share and I set all as parameter for function and works. But perfect solution will be access to view variables.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't go in your View, it should be in your controller.

**Controller**

```
$name = Helpers::setLetters('variable_name');
return \View::make('yourview', array( 'variable_name' => $name);
```